# How can I make a steady automata in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, automata

I'm working on a javascript game and I've got an automata system controlling game time and sprite animation as well as giving a hand to the path finding system for timing and such. My problem is on slow browsers the javascript loop I'm using for counting the time is not very accurate. It tends to jump around a lot. I there a way to force the loop to run consistently at 30 fps?

Basically I need a way of keeping my automata loop running at 1/30th of a second.

Comment: Are you saying you need it to run every 1/30th of a second, and if it drops a frame it waits 1/15th of a second? Or are you saying you need it to have an accurate way of determining the time, regardless of how often it runs?

Comment: Ya, feels like you're asking two different things: if you really need to achieve a consistent 30fps, then you need a way to ensure all processing for each frame happens in < 33⅓ milliseconds. OTOH, if you need to ensure that movement / animation completes at a consistent rate, then you can drop frames when processing gets too heavy - as tloflin notes, you just need a reliable way to gauge elapsed time. What have you tried so far, and how is it failing?

Comment: A “javascript loop to count the time” sounds very ominous. Please tell us you *are* using `setInterval` here and not some dodgy busy-loop, yeah?

Comment: ah.. @bobince I've been using setTimeout to re execute functions in a loop. I forgot about set interval. I'll go clean that up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems useing set interval instead of a self invoking function with setTimeout sped thing up quite a bit. thanks bobince

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for you to control the timing (have a read up [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/) for more info), but without some more info I'm afraid I can't help you more.